# Vagrant/VirtualBox guest doesn't boot completely after upgrading Ubuntu guest from 14 to 16

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, vagrant

I have a running WEB server with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with LAMP environment. The server is running in a Vagrant/VirtualBox virtual machine.

I made a release upgrade to Ubuntu 16. The upgrade had no error, but after I restarted the guest system I could not log in through ssh into the guest. it did not give me login prompt on the gui. The last messages can be seen here:

[image]

The appropriate VirtualBox process is using 100% CPU on the host.

I don't see any error in the VirtualBox log. It is absolutely the same as th log of successful booting with Ubuntu 14. But the log ends with the following lines:

```
00:00:03.373112 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:03.373373 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=1, bootseq=0002
00:00:03.373822 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from Hard Disk...
00:00:04.464068 PIT: mode=2 count=0x12a5 (4773) - 249.98 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:04.740030 PIT: mode=0 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:04.746800 CPUM: VCPU  1: Cached APIC base MSR = 0xfee00800
00:00:06.067801 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:06.094234 AHCI#0: Port 0 reset
00:00:08.520691 NAT: Link up
```

while the old (successful one) continues:

```
00:00:04.310395 PIT: mode=2 count=0x12a5 (4773) - 249.98 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:04.670117 PIT: mode=0 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:04.675933 CPUM: VCPU  1: Cached APIC base MSR = 0xfee00800
00:00:06.058491 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:06.067719 AHCI#0: Port 0 reset
00:00:08.049147 NAT: Link up
00:00:10.181385 VMMDev: Guest Additions information report: Version 4.3.36 r105129 '4.3.36_Ubuntu'
00:00:10.181441 VMMDev: Guest Additions information report: Interface = 0x00010004 osType = 0x00053100 (Linux >= 2.6, 64-bit)
00:00:10.181529 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x0) seamless: no, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no
```

May be, that something with the guest addition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed at length a while back at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771871/16-04-virtualbox-vm-from-vhd-file-hangs-at-non-blocking-pool-is-initialized). In short, it tries to initialize a non-existent serial console and fails miserably. You should either attach virtual serial port with VirtualBox or remove `console=ttyS0` from Grub boot menu options.

Comment: Enabling and configuring COM1 az raw file in VirtualBox manager solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: The final solution was the removing of `console=ttyS0` from `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg` and running `update-grub`.